# Appending to JSON Arrays in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, json

I have a JSON array structured like this

```
{"data":[{"Chris":[{"long":10,"lat":19}]},{"Scott":[{"long":9,"lat":18}]}]}
```

I then append to this array in a Ruby application like so

```
RbHash = JSON.parse(File.open('public/test.json').read);
RbHash["data"] << {Usrname: [{long: Lng.to_i, lat: Lat.to_i}]}
```

My problem is that the Usrname variable is added to the JSON array as "Usrname" and not its actual value. How is this fixed?

Comment: Your hash looks suspicious. Are you generating it or receiving it? Individual hashes embedded in single-element arrays looks like something upstream is not written right. Also, don't use `RbHash` for variables you're going to change, even if it's a hash. Constants start with capital letters, variables start with lower-case.

Comment: @theTinMan Yeah I know the variable name for the hash is weird, I was just making sure there wasn't a problem with the variable before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want `Usrname:`, don't use `Usrname:` the symbol as your key.

```
RbHash["data"] << {"blah" => [{long: Lng.to_i, lat: Lat.to_i}]}
```

RE Your comments:

> I want the key to be equal to a variable (Username). –

You need to use old hash syntax then. When you use `Username:`, you're defining a symbol as the key; if you want to use a variable's value as the key, you need to use `Username => ...`:

```
RbHash["data"] << { Username => [{long: Lng.to_i, lat: Lat.to_i}]}
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. I want the key to be equal to a variable (Username).

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.